# Python Encoding Error when writing to file

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I want write some strings to file which is not in English, they are in Azeri language. Even if I do utf-8 encoding I get following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

my code piece that wants to write to file is following:

```
        t_w = text_list[y].encode('utf-8')
        new_file.write(t_w.decode('utf-8'))
        new_file.write('\n')
```

EDIT

Even if I make code as:

```
        t_w = text_list[y].encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
        new_file.write(t_w)
        new_file.write('\n')
```

I get following error which is :

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Don't decode while writing in file. Just use new_file.write(t_w). Decode while reading from file like `file.read().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: then I get following error:
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: If you're ok with losing data you can set `.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')`. You can read more about it [here in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type).

Comment: @IsmailKerimov open file in binary mode.  `open('abc.txt', 'wb')`

Comment: @Dheerendra I am also writing another things as int string to file so that i cannot make all of them bytes

Comment: @blakev even if I am okay with that I get: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell `t_w.decode(...)` attempts to convert your characters to ASCII, which doesn't encode some Azeri characters. There is no need to decode the string because you want to write it to the file as UTF-8, so omit the `.decode(...)` part:`new_file.write(t_w)`

Comment: I edited my answer you can see what happens when i make it as you said